# How to make a top sheet fragment dialog in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

Would someone tell me how to open a custom dialog from top screen? Just like in this image?

[image]

I tried using `BottomSheetFragment()` and everything works fine in bottom sheet fragment but I cant set its behaviour like top sheet fragment and I need to do that.

Comment: Appbar with increasing height transition and bottom rounded corner shape(from drawable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android "Top Sheet" equivalent of "Bottom Sheet"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088269/android-top-sheet-equivalent-of-bottom-sheet)

Comment: I gone through this question but didnt get any help! @MidasLefko

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the default bottom sheet provided by google as it is the "bottom" sheet. however, I have used [this](https://github.com/ipuris/AndroidTopSheet/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/techisfun/android/topsheet/TopSheetBehavior.java) in the past here is a complete[example](https://github.com/ipuris/AndroidTopSheet) for it

Comment: But the problem with this library is, you cant show the layout like custom dialog view.

its just simply transition a view

Comment: you can make a custom view by inheriting from this

Comment: Simple things like this are not easy to do in Android.
This is drawback of Android Development